# clang++ problems on macOS Mojave

Tags: c++, macos, clang

I have a problem compiling on my mac. It works perfectly on Linux but with Xcode it just doesn't work. Apparently it has a problem using the random function from XcodeDefault.xctoolchain. Anybody knows a walk-around for this problem?

I tried to compile c++ code from github

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/random:3649:34: error: 
      call to non-static member function without an object argument
    const _RealType _Rp = _URNG::max() - _URNG::min() + _RealType(1);
```

there are clang errors when I try to compile.

Comment: Show us your code.

Comment: The problem is very likely not inside the standard library header file but in the code you try to build.

Comment: ok I see thanks. I'm new to c++ I thought beceause it works with my Linux machine it probably has something to do with the header file.

Comment: A standard header can include other headers. It is not defined which header includes which other header. Your code should not depend on transient includes. Include everything you need yourself. Usually when something like this happens it's caused by undefined behavior in your code. Please provide a [mcve].